# How do I use Rigidbody.MovePosition with Input.GetAxis acting as my direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

```cs
void Update()
    {
        MovementAxes = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        HandleMovement(MovementAxes, 60f);
    }



    void HandleMovement(Vector2 direction, float MovementAmount)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("w") || Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            if (Input.GetKey("w") && GroundCheck())
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (direction * MovementAmount * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
            }
            else if (Input.GetKey("s") && !GroundCheck())
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (direction * MovementAmount * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
            }
        }
}
```

I have the code above that uses `Input.GetAxis` to act as the `direction` param for the two `MovePosition` methods that move a Dynamic Rigidbody.

When the "s" key is pressed the object goes downs as expected but when the "w" key is pressed the object jitters, going slightly up and down, but inconsistent during. I've printed out `distance` when "w" key was pressed, the value of Input.GetAxis("Vertical") was negative and positive.

How do I use MovePosition to move the gameobject with constancy. I'd rather use MovePosition rather than other `Rigidbody` methods since it's said to "create a smooth transition between frames."(unity)

Comment: why get the Input twice? do you need the ones in `FixedUpdate` at all? I would rather already handle these in `Update` and not get the Input again in `FixedUpdate` at all .. also what is `GroundCheck()` doing?

Comment: @derHugo When you say "get Input twice"  do you mean getting the input for the Horizontal and Vertical axes and getting the input for key w and s? If so I got the input for the two because I wanted to get the direction of the object without having to place it myself (why I got Horizontal and Vertical input), and I got the input for key w and s because I wanted the two to do certain actions.

Comment: For some reason the correct answer was deleted!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I would suggest to use `AddForce` to your `Rigidbody2D`.
Here is a sample script with a very simple `2D Movement` in Unity.

```cs
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D _rigidBody2d;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Cache the value, don't call GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() in FixedUpdate
        _rigidBody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Store horizontal and vertical movement
        var moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        var moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        
        // Create the actual movement
        var movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, moveVertical);

        // apply it to your rigidbody by using AddForce
        _rigidBody2d.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn't AddForce give a sliding feel, or can I get rid of that with friction? And why not call ```GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()```  in ```FixedUpdate```?

Comment: For performance reasons. `GetComponent` is not the lightest function since it check all the `Components` attached to a `GameObject` and calling this in almost every `Update` is not a good practice. You won't feel the difference from just one script but imagine to have 100 GameObjects with more than 50 components and calling this function in every one of them in `Update` or `FixedUpdate`. Cache and reuse data as much as you can if you want to write code with better performance.

Comment: I think the `Input.GetAxis()` should be called in the `Update()` method not the `FixedUpdate()` to avoid missing inputs from the user.